# Where are the FaunaDB functions called "Delete" and "Collections"?

Tags: c#, faunadb

I'm a noob at FaunaDB. I have successfully added a collection to a database and have queried a record from that collection. Now I want to delete the collection. I have followed the example [here](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/cookbook/basics/collections/delete?lang=csharp) but on both the Delete and Collection functions, it says "The name 'Delete/Collection' does not exist in the current context"

I have these using at the top of the code.

```
using FaunaClient = FaunaDB.Client;
using FaunaTypes = FaunaDB.Types;
```

[image]

I've made sure my NuGet packages are all on the latest versions. I've tried dot-walking all the classes in FaunaDB to find them but to no avail. What gives?

Comment: Have you added the appropriate `using static` statement, as seen in "Usage" in [the guide](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/drivers/csharp)?

Comment: Yes. Adding the collection and querying it wouldn't have worked without them.
using FaunaClient = FaunaDB.Client;
using FaunaTypes = FaunaDB.Types;

Comment: I meant `using static FaunaDB.Query.Language`.

Comment: argh! I had that in my original class when testing adding and querying, but somehow overlooked it when I re-wrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods you're trying to access are all static methods on [the `Language` struct](https://github.com/fauna/faunadb-csharp/blob/d3e651aa396a79f04605690b1ae252eb2d0bb154/FaunaDB.Client/Query/Language.Write.cs). To access them in the way shown in the FaunaDB tutorials, you need to add a static reference to `FaunaDB.Query.Language`:

```cs
using static FaunaDB.Query.Language;
```